# Move Block into New Block/Template

Tags: magento2, blocks, template

I have created a couple of new templates that replace the header on my theme and I've created a new header container that contains the new blocks I'm using to render the templates.

What I want to know is, how do I go about pulling through the catalogue top navigation (store/category navigation) into one of these blocks? What is considered best practice?

Thanks

Gareth

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to use `<move>` tag to move catalog navigation to your container. eg:

```
<move element="catalog.topnav" destination="your_container_name"/>
```

Comment: Yes, this is the approach I have gone for, thanks.